# Converting normalised floating point binary to denary

Tags: floating-point, binary

What should you do when some data of a binary number gets lost when you shift the values to convert them? I'll add an example below. I'm going to write my working in case anything is wrong!

Suppose we have the binary number (8-bit mantissa, 4-bit exponent, both in two's complement) **`10100011 1100`**.

Since the exponent is -4, that means we have to shift the decimal point left by 4. Since the number is negative (leading 1) we fill with 1s instead of 0s to get **`11111010`**.

I have a few questions.

1. What now happens with the extra data that was lost off the end (i.e. the **`0011`**)?
2. Was I correct by adding 1s to the start as the original normalised number started with a 1?
3. Would I fill with 1s or 0s if the exponent was positive (and what would happen to the data lost?)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. What now happens with the extra data that was lost off the end (i.e. the **`0011`**)?

There is a choice. Most often, the outgoing digits are used to round the result. If the digits were just discarded, the result would be some number *x*. In the floating-point number, there is some number just above *x*, say *y*. E.g., with six binary digits, after 1.00011, there is 1.00100. Let *z* be the number we would have if we could keep the digits. Then *z* is between *x* and *y* (possibly exactly *x*), and it is either closer to *x*, closer to *y*, or equally close. If we are rounding to the nearest representable value, we use *x* if it is closer and *y* if it is closer. If there is a tie, the most commonly used rule rounds to whichever of *x* or *y* has an even low digit.

However, there are other rules. You could break ties by rounding to the odd digit, which helps preserve the fact that information has been lost. You could discard the digits, always choosing *x*, effectively rounding toward zero. You could round toward whichever of *x* or *y* is lower, effectively rounding toward −∞. Or you could round to the greater, effectively rounding toward +∞.

> 2. Was I correct by adding 1s to the start as the original normalised number started with a 1?

The most common formats used for floating-point do not use two’s complement. They would extend the number with zeros, not any sign extension.

If you are using two’s complement, then you extend the significand field on the “left” (the direction of increasing position values) with sign extension.

> 3. Would I fill with 1s or 0s if the exponent was positive (and what would happen to the data lost?)?

The digits on the right of the number are all zeros already. E.g., if we have the number 1.00011, it is 1.000110000000000000…